# Nucleophilicity of amines

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3acp.jpg]

I think the bridge head nitrogens won't react.The answer is B C A. Can someone help me, please

Comment: What type of reaction is it? What are the products? How will the two reactants approach to make the new bond? Please edit to share how far you got in making and argument. Why do you think the bridge nitrogens won't react.

Comment: Am not sure. I thought it was a nucleophillic reaction.  Can you please help me with what type of reaction it is and why bridge head amine is more reactive.

Comment: @Karsten Theis , this problem is from MS Chowhan , in chapter amines and their reactivity. This book is generally used by students preparing for IIT entrance exam in India.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks context. Could you edit the question to show what the nucleophile and what the electrophile is, what mechanism you expect and what products you anticipate?

Comment: Is this the reaction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menshutkin_reaction

Comment: https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2018/05/07/nucleophilicity-of-amines/

Comment: @ Nivedita , In the current form ,your question may be closed.SE expects you to include your thoughts regarding your question in your post.

Comment: @Nivedita  the bridgehead amines do react. Consider which amines have most steric hindrance

Comment: A chemical reaction (here an SN2 reaction) is just zillions of molecules hitting each others in a certain direction and with a certain kinetic energy. If the angle is right and the energy is right, then the reaction can occur. With A, there is a large chance that the ethyl groups (which are free to move) just get in the way, but not for B and C (imagine them like A has its hands cuffed in its back). However, I have always been told that C is more nucleophilic than B.